# HttpServletRequest getRequestURI in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a SpringBoot ap. with this method in the controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/")
public String home(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("home ->" + request.getRequestURI() + "<-");
}
```

but when I do from the console:

```
curl localhost:7080
curl localhost:7080/./
curl localhost:7080/../
curl localhost:7080/..
```

I always get the same result: `home ->/<-`

and the same result with the browser. and I would like to return 404 for all the mapping that are not `localhost:7080`

I've tried:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-nunito:~ nunito$ curl --path--as-is localhost:7080/./
curl: option --path--as-is: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information


 curl --version
curl 7.64.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0) libcurl/7.64.1 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/2.8.3 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.41.0
Release-Date: 2019-03-27
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets
```

Comment: Ok. Is there a question?

Comment: Is there a way to return 404 for all the mappings different that / ?

Comment: Sorry typo in flag please use `curl --path-as-is localhost:7080/./`. I accidently added extra `-` before `as`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These should already be blocked as they contain path traversal. They are not valid request.

Curl is modifying them before sending to spring just like browser does. You could use `--path-as-is` flag to instruct curl to send the url as is.

Something like

```
curl --path-as-is localhost:7080/./
```

Once you do this you should get internal server error with the `RequestedRejectedException`.

There is open jira to change this to 400 by default - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7568

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking help from 3PP libraries. Example below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
  <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And add a class that will put proper complete URL into the request scope before the request reaches the actual controller

```
public class LogbookSink implements Sink {

    @Override
    public void write(final Precorrelation precorrelation, final HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        request.setAttribute("complete_url", request.getRequestUri());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final Correlation correlation, final HttpRequest request, final HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        //do something else for response
    }
}
```

Now in the controller, you can simply get the exact "called" URI by saying

```
String calledUri = request.getAttribute("complete_url");
//your logic to throw 404
//if (!calledUri.matches("localhost:7080/")){
//    throw new ResponseStatusException(NOT_FOUND, "Unable to find resource");
//}
```